# Spring Security intercept URL access not working as expected

Tags: java, xml, spring-boot, spring-security

I am working on spring security namespace configuration.there is a problem in accessing some pages where intercept url denied to access that page.`

http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.1.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.1.xsd">

```
    <http use-expressions="true">
    <headers>
        <frame-options policy="SAMEORIGIN" />
    </headers>
    <csrf disabled="true" />

    <intercept-url pattern="/projectlist" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />
```

```
    <intercept-url pattern="/projectboard/*" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_OWNER','ROLE_MEMBER')" />

    <access-denied-handler error-page="/access" />

    <form-login login-page='/login' login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check"
        default-target-url="/dashboard"  always-use-default-target="false"
        authentication-failure-url="/login?error=true" username-parameter="username"
        password-parameter="password" />

    <logout logout-url="/logout" logout-success-url="/logoutSuccessful"
        delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" invalidate-session="true" />

        <remember-me key="myAppKey" token-validity-seconds="864000" />

    </http>

<authentication-manager>

    <authentication-provider>
        <password-encoder ref="encoder" />
        <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
            users-by-username-query="select username,password,enabled from user where username=?"
            authorities-by-username-query="select * from ( (Select u.username,'ROLE_OWNER' user_role from user u inner join project_user pu on u.user_id = pu.user_id) UNION (Select u.username,'ROLE_MEMBER' user_role from user u inner join member m on u.user_id = m.user_id) UNION (Select ur.username,'ROLE_USER' user_role from user_roles ur inner join user u on u.username=ur.username)) as users where username =? group by user_role" />
    </authentication-provider> 
</authentication-manager>


<beans:bean id="encoder"
    class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder">
    <beans:constructor-arg name="strength" value="10" />
</beans:bean>
```

`
 This file is working when the user login and access the "/setting/*" URL (that page is only accessible for owner not for member). but when the new user is register and directly access the page (even he is a owner), intercept url won't allow him to access the page. After he logout and again login to the system, he can able to access the "/setting/*" URL page. I don't know ,where i was wrong.

any help appreciated.Thank you in advance.